# How to change value of cell in excel with no fill

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet in excel where colored cells contain values, and cells with no fill are empty. I would like all cells with no fill color to have value `0`. I have code that I have used to give black and yellow cells values `1` and `2` respectively.

```
Sub changeValuesBasedOnColour()

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim xRg As Range
    Set xRg = Selection.Cells
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each rg In xRg
        With rg
            Select Case .Interior.Color
                Case Is = 0   'Black
                    .Value = 1
                Case Is = 65535 'Yellow
                    .Value = 2
                Case Is = xlNone
                    .Value = 0
                
             End Select
        End With
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

I have edited my code that I used to change value of cells based on fill color to include this section:

```
 Case Is = xlNone
   .Value = 0
```

However there is no change in my spreadsheet. How can I edit my code to refer to the cells with no fill color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vbWhite` or `16777215`.

`xlNone` is applicable to the cell's `.Interior.ColorIndex`, which is not the same as `.Interior.Color`.

Answer (score 0):

### `Color` Does Not Distinguish `NoFill` From `White`!?

Since `vbWhite` or `16777215` used with the `Color` property will allow to write to **white** and **not filled** cells, I would suggest you use the `ColorIndex` property.

```
Select Case .Interior.ColorIndex
    Case Is = 1 ' Black
        .Value = 1
    Case Is = 6 ' Yellow
        .Value = 2
    Case Is = xlNone ' No color
        .Value = 0
     Case Else
End Select
```

or:

```
If .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone Then
    .Value = 0          ' No Fill
Else
    Select Case .Interior.Color
        Case Is = 0     ' Black
            .Value = 1
        Case Is = 65535 ' Yellow
            .Value = 2
        Case Else
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: You'd have to go with the second code snippet... as the index of colors varies according to the current palette (as I'm guessing you know).

Comment: I totally forgot about that. Thx.